# European ETF with dividends reinvested?

Tags: etf, dividends

Is anyone aware of an ETF that invests in the European market according to some index and that reinvests its dividends automatically? I can't seem to find it.

I am aware of DRIP that some brokers offer which reinvests the dividends on investor's behalf. But you still have to pay the dividends tax I'd like to avoid that and the bureaucracy that comes with it.

If there's no such ETF, the next best thing for me would be a world ETF with dividends reinvested.

Comment: Product/service recommendation questions are off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 1):

> Is anyone aware of an ETF that invests in the European market according to some index and that reinvests its dividends automatically?

This is essentially an ETF which pays out no dividends, instead focusing on capital gains. It might be difficult to find one which pays out zero dividends, but you may wish to look specifically for European ETFs which pay out small dividends in order to minimize the dividends taxes.

Comment: Are you aware of any such ETFs? How to search for them? It seems much easier to find ETFs that focus on dividend stocks than the opposite.

Comment: I was unable to find any, but that doesn't mean they don't exist.

Comment: Thanks. I've found IWDE which is an international euro-hedged ETF that doesn't pay out dividends.

Answer (score 1):

I've found it.  The dividend-reinvesting Europe ETF is `SMEA` (full name: *iShares MSCI Europe UCITS ETF EUR (Acc)*).

Other non-dividend-paying ETFs of interest to me are:

- `SWDA` - world ETF, dividends reinvested,
- `IWDE` - world ETF, dividends reinvested, EUR hedged.

The key was to search for phrases such as: *european ETF accumulating*, specifically the *accumulating* part. I've tried to search using *dividends reinvested* before with no success.